# What does "fcn" stand for when naming callback functions?

Tags: terminology

Frequently I find callback functions called something fcn, but I can't figure out what fcn stands for or what it is a contraction of. What does fcn stand for?

e.g. my_callback_fcn as defined here

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/timer-callback-functions.html

Comment: Um... maybe "function"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's short for "Function" by pronunciation.

You can find the following in that page:

"StartFcn",
"StopFcn",
"TimerFcn",
"ErrorFcn",